# Confluence server plugin not working in data center

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I have made a plugin for Confluence v7.13.7. It is working absolutely fine in the Confluence server which is set up locally on my machine. But, when I tried installing the plugin in the client’s instance who is also using the same Confluence version 7.13.7 but using the data center version, the plugin got installed but not giving any result upon hitting the API endpoint.

Is this possible that a plugin can work in a server edition but cannot work in the data center? If this can happen, what are the possible reasons for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://developer.atlassian.com/platform/marketplace/developing-apps-for-atlassian-data-center-products/ to learn the difference of apps for DC. Most features will work the same it DC as in Server, but as it uses several nodes, you have to think how to transfer the same objects between them